# Parse string for unicode characters in C#

Tags: c#, parsing, unicode

I have an input form where someone is allowed to type unicode characters. So it might be something like "Hey \uF32A what's up?". If I get this string it will have a substring of "\uF32A" how do i turn that to the character '\uF32A'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Regular Expression to [Unescape](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.unescape(v=vs.110).aspx) as shown below:

```
var str = @"Hey \uF32A what's up?";    
System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Unescape(str);
```